# how to setup Coc-Angular lsp extension in COC neo vim

Tags: angular, vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm trying to move to Nvim for a long time and trying to set it up for react/angular . i got around and finished setup for react since the jsx plugin and others was enough for it but I'm currently stuck with setting it up for angular language service with COC.vim using the coc-angular extension

so, as per the [coc-angular](https://github.com/iamcco/coc-angular) readme I installed it and and started a fresh new Angular project with a new eslint config problem is that when i open a html file the language service does not work and **CocInfo** produces this output

```
## Output channel: angular                                                                          
   12                                                                                                     
   13 [Info  - 10:44:07 AM] Angular language server process ID: 7266                                      
   14 [Info  - 10:44:07 AM] Using typescript v3.9.7 from /home/arshad/.config/coc/extensions/node_modules/coc-angular/node_modules/types
   15 [Info  - 10:44:07 AM] Using @angular/language-service v10.0.4 from /home/arshad/.config/coc/extensions/node_modules/coc-angular/no
   16 [Info  - 10:44:07 AM] Log file: /tmp/nglangsvc.log                                                  
   17 [Info  - 10:44:15 AM] Enabling language service for /home/arshad/Documents/angularLSP/tsconfig.json.
   18 [Error  - 10:44:15 AM] No config file for /home/arshad/Documents/angularLSP/src/app/app.component.html
```

i dont understand what the error means and what should i do in order to overcome this, i've added the angular language service to plugins in TSconfig
these are my configs for vim , Coc and TSconfig

1. [init.vim](https://github.com/arshadpakkali/vim-config/blob/master/init.vim)
2. coc-config =>

```
{                                                                                                   
 "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": ["css", "markdown","javascript","typescript","JSON"],     
}
```

3. Tsconfig =>

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "plugins": [{ "name": "@angular/language-service" }],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

any Help is highly appreciated. if there's any other thread related to this please link me to those and will be highly useful to me because I'm kind of new to vim my laptop cant handle vscode . and feel free to give me any other vim config related recommendations and Plugins for angular

Thanks :D

Comment: I never used coc myself but it looks to me like your coc.vim config is missing the configuration for your actual language server, see [coc doc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Language-servers)

Comment: Thanks for looking up man , but i just realized that im getting this error for my main folder in vscode too so i this might be config issue too